# How to subscribe a new member to mailchamp using node.js and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web-deployment, mailchimp

I am trying to work with an API, specifically mail-chimp API, but the problem that I am having is:

```js
const express=require("express");
const bodyparser=require("body-parser");
const request=require("request");
const https=require("https");
const app=express();


app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.get("/",function(req,res){
res.sendFile(__dirname + "/signup.html");

});

app.post("/", function(req,res){
const firstName=req.body.fName;
const lastName=req.body.lName;
const email=req.body.email;

const data={
  members: [{

    email_adress:email,
    status: "subscribed",
    merge_fields:{
      FNAME:firstName,
      LNAME:lastName,
    }
  }
  ]
}

var jsonData=JSON.stringify(data);
//"https://us18.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/list/024346747a3"
const url="https://us18.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/0243b2d7a3/members";
const options={
  method:"POST",
  auth:"john:be1fa777676767686835387837-us20"
}

const request=https.request(url, options,function(response){
  response.on("data",function(data){
    console.log(JSON.parse(data));
  });
  request.write(jsonData);
  req.end();
});

//console.log(firstName + " ....... " + lastName + " ......  " + email);

});

//api key
//be1fa777676767686835387837-us20

//list // ID
//0243b2d7a3

app.listen(3000,function(){
console.log("server is running on port 3000");
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.form-signin {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 330px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: auto;
}

.form-signin .checkbox {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.form-signin .form-floating:focus-within {
  z-index: 2;
}

.middle{
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-bottom:-1px;
}

.top {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.bottom{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
    <meta name="generator" content="Hugo 0.88.1">
    <title>News letter sign up</title>

    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/examples/sign-in/">



    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Favicons -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/docs/5.1/assets/img/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png" sizes="180x180">
<link rel="icon" href="/docs/5.1/assets/img/favicons/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" type="image/png">
<link rel="icon" href="/docs/5.1/assets/img/favicons/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" type="image/png">
<link rel="manifest" href="/docs/5.1/assets/img/favicons/manifest.json">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="/docs/5.1/assets/img/favicons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#7952b3">
<link rel="icon" href="/docs/5.1/assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#7952b3">


    <style>
      .bd-placeholder-img {
        font-size: 1.125rem;
        text-anchor: middle;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
      }

      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
          font-size: 3.5rem;
        }
      }
    </style>


    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body class="text-center">

<main class="form-signin">
  <form action="/" method="POST">
    <img class="mb-4" src="Images/santa.png" alt="" width="72" height="57">
    <h1 class="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">Sign up to my newsletter</h1>

    <input type="text" name="fName" class="form-control top" placeholder="First Name" required autofocus>
      <input type="text" name="lName" class="form-control midle" placeholder="last Name" required>
      <input type="password" name="email" class="form-control bottom" placeholder="Email" required>


    <button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Sign me up</button>
    <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2017–2021</p>
  </form>
</main>



  </body>
</html>
```

so, That was the code, I have to say that I am learning, and this from a course. It does not work me when I am trying to do it, and I would to understand why:

also this this what my terminal is saying:
[This is the what my terminal is complaining about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nu9pK.png)

[and I am connected localhost port 3000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcaSV.png)

Answer (score 0):

Me too learning from same course and stuck with the same problem, then I went through the mailchimp api [documentation](https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/api/lists/batch-subscribe-or-unsubscribe/) and came up with the following code (it worked for me):

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mailchimp = require("@mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.listen( 3000, () => {
    console.log("server is listening at 3000");
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/signup.html");
});

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
    const fname = req.body.Fname;
    const lname = req.body.Lname;
    const email = req.body.email;

    mailchimp.setConfig({
        apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY",
        server: "YOUR_SERVER_PREFIX",
    });

    const run = async () => {
        const response = await mailchimp.lists.batchListMembers("3230304ca4", {
            members: [
                {
                    email_address: email,
                    status: "subscribed",
                    merge_fields: {
                        FNAME: fname,
                        LNAME: lname,
                    },
                },
            ],
        });

        if (response.error_count) {
            res.sendFile(__dirname + "/failure.html");
        } else {
            res.sendFile(__dirname + "/success.html");
        }
    };

    run();
});

app.post("/failure", (req, res) => {
    res.redirect("/");
});
```

You need to install mailchimp library through [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing) by the following command

```js
npm install @mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing
```

Have a look at example [responses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79xcp.png) in the [documentation](https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/api/lists/batch-subscribe-or-unsubscribe/) sent by the mailchimp API if you have any errors.